# Lousy "My Computer"

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer

I have a problem with "My Computer" or "This PC" or "Windows File Explorer", whatever you may call it. When I press Windows+E to open "This PC", there are no drives shown and it keeps on loading and loading. But when I press Windows+E to open it again and again, it is opened perfectly in two or three tries.

Also some file icons are displayed as if they were unknown files.

I have windows 8.1 in my laptop.

I have tried changing antivirus and now using Avast which caught many viruses. Windows Defender did not.

I have tried rebuilding icon cache. But when I refresh on the desktop, icon become weird again.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Most likely a virus corrupted your Windows installation. I suggest you reinstall from scratch.

Comment: If you got any usb storage devices attached, windows might have trouble loading it (hence the loading). Detach it and try again.

Comment: Also, related: [“Discovering items”… yawn](http://superuser.com/q/204247/228536) (because you mention the loading aspect at the start). I did give an answer there that explains that messing with security permissions within the Registry can have such effects.

Comment: I used the Safe Mode recently, and everything works fine there !

Comment: You could try MSCONFIG to ensure nothing is loading which shouldn't be! Or, remove the ethernet connection and see if that helps.